# ASMX WebMethod Incorrect Namespace Result In Empty Parameters

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx

I am integrating with a 3rd party and I have to create ASMX web service as per their standard to be called by them, where they enforce me to use their hard-coded SOAP Action, say it is "http://tempuri.org/SomeWebService/", now the problem is once they call my web service, I am receiving parameters as empty string, where after I checked the logs, I found they set a different namespace in WebMethod tag as "http://tempuri.org/" where it seems this avoid .NET from parsing parameters properly, here is a sample Envelope I receive:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<SomeWebMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<SomeField>abc123</SomeField>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now as I can not request the 3rd party developers to update their code base, then I need to find a workaround to let .NET not to validate namespace tag for WebMethod, so is there a chance to accomplish this?

Please note that I checked the POST request and all parameters were their in XML body along with their assigned values but again .NET was unable to parse them into method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using SoapDocumentMethod:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(
Action="http://tempuri.org/SomeWebService/SomeWebMethod",
RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",
RequestElementName="SomeWebMethod")]
[WebMethod] 
public string SomeWebMethod(string SomeField)
{
    // Implementation ...
}
```